# Nestjs: Route Parameter

Tags: express, nestjs

Is there a way to add callback triggers to route parameters. [Express Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html)
For example:

```
app.param('startDate', handleDateParameter);
```

I would like for it t work only for specific routes, example `api/reports/getDailyReports/:startDate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest's concept of [`Pipes`](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) might be the answer to your problem.

You would use it at the method/route level (as opposed to global/module/controller levels) in your controller using `@Param('name', YourCustomPipe)` in your route.

***Example***:
First, define your custom `HandleDateParameter` pipe:

```js
// handle-date-parameter.pipe.ts
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, HttpStatus, 
BadRequestException } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class HandleDateParameter implements PipeTransform<string, number> {
  transform(value: string, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
    // ...implement your custom logic here to validate your date for example or do whatever you want :)
    // finally you might want to return your custom value or throw an exception (i.e: throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed'))
    return myCustomValue;
  }
}
```

And then use it in your controller:

```js
// reports.controller.ts  
// Make your imports here (HandleDateParameter and other stuff you need)
@Controller('reports')
export class ReportsController {
    @Get('getDailyReports/:startDate')
    // The following line is where the magic happens :) (you will handle the startDate param in your pipe
    findDailyReports(@Param('startDate', HandleDateParameter) startDate: Date) {
        //.... your custom logic here
        return myResult;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helps you ;)

Comment: looks promising, but would i need to call the pipe for every routes (everytime i use the "startDate" parameter in this controller)?

Comment: Yes, from my perspective you would have to call it on every route using this parameter. Or if every routes of your controller use it, you might want to use it at the controller level, like so: 

    @Controller('reports')
    @UsePipes(HandleDateParameterPipe)
    export class ReportsController {
        @Get('getDailyReports/:startDate') { 
             // ... you code here  
        } 
    }